# SQL query with EXISTS not working as I thought

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi these two SQL Queries return the same result

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemID
FROM Sale INNER JOIN Department
ON Department.DepartmentID = Sale.DepartmentID
WHERE DepartmentFloor = 2
ORDER BY ItemID


SELECT DISTINCT ItemID
FROM Sale
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM Department
WHERE Sale.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID
AND DepartmentFloor = 2)
ORDER BY ItemID;
```

The Subquery Inside the Exists returns True So why doesnt the secod query return the equivalent of

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemID
FROM Sale
```

Which guves a different result from the two above.

Comment: Does the subquery always return true? It seems that some sale department id's are not on floor 2

Comment: Yes, but I thought that once one of them returned True, then SELECT DISTINCT ItemID
FROM Sale gets executed

Comment: If a Department is only DepartmentFloor=1 or if the DepartmentID didn't have a Sale record, then the EXISTS query will return FALSE for the row in Sale and exclude the record for that DepartmentID.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused by `EXISTS()`.. It occurs on a line by line basis, based on table correlation, not just a single true/false.  This line of your subquery is your correlation clause:

```
Sale.DepartmentID = Department.DepartmentID
```

It is saying "Only show the Sale.ItemIDs where that ItemID's Sale.DepartmentID is in Department."

It achieves the same function as a join predicate, like in your first query:

```
FROM Sale S
JOIN Department D on S.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID --here
```

Conversely, this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemID
FROM Sale
```

Has no limiting factor.

As an aside, you also further limit the results of each query with:

```
WHERE DepartmentFloor = 2
```

But I don't think that is the part that is throwing you off, I think it is the concept that a correlated subquery occurs for each record.  If you were to remove your correlating clause, then the subquery would actually return true always, and you would get all results back.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery isn't always returning true. It will evaluate for each row, joining on DepartmentID where the DepartmentFloor is 2.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01c42a/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Sale ( ItemID int, DepartmentID int ) ;

INSERT INTO Sale ( ItemID, DepartmentID )
VALUES (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,1), (5,4), (6,2), (7,3), (8,4) ;

CREATE TABLE Department ( DepartmentID int, DepartmentFloor int ) ;

INSERT INTO Department ( DepartmentID, DepartmentFloor )
VALUES (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,2) ;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Department
WHERE DepartmentFloor = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01c42a/7/0)**: This lists only the Departments on DepartmentFloor 2.

```
| DepartmentID | DepartmentFloor |
|--------------|-----------------|
|            3 |               2 |
|            4 |               2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sale
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01c42a/7/1)**: This lists ALL of your Sales.

```
| ItemID | DepartmentID |
|--------|--------------|
|      1 |            1 |
|      2 |            2 |
|      3 |            3 |
|      4 |            1 |
|      5 |            4 |
|      6 |            2 |
|      7 |            3 |
|      8 |            4 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sale
WHERE DepartmentID IN (3,4)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01c42a/7/2)**: And this one shows what is the equivalent of you EXISTS statement. It only shows 4 rows that will match up in my data. So you'd only get back ItemIDs 3,5,7 and 8.

```
| ItemID | DepartmentID |
|--------|--------------|
|      3 |            3 |
|      5 |            4 |
|      7 |            3 |
|      8 |            4 |
```

Answer (score 0):

because the uppper part of the query is equivalent  to

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ItemID FROM Sale where EXISTS (true)
```

the upper  is the only query that really check the condition ..

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. If the subquery returns true, shouldn't the query 
    SELECT DISTINCT ItemID
    FROM Sale be executed?

Comment: is exactly the opposite where true means "in each case" (in this context) is equivalent to where 1 = 1   ..